Trouble Installing after booting on Thinkpad T430
I've recently been trying to install Ubuntu on my T430. After getting through the booting process and to the installation I get an error message that says
"We're sorry, but we're not sure what the error is. You can try restarting your computer and start the installation process again"
I already have Secure Boot disabled
I've already tried restarting and that hasn't changed anything
I've tried switching from USB 3.0 to USB 2.0 Flash drive
The laptop has 4gb of RAM is that just not enough for the installation? I'm also doing this on a completely fresh Samsung SSD but I don't think that matters
EDIT:
After checking gparted it seems I needed to create a partition for the SSD. This got me through some of the installation process, but I'm still getting the same error

Boot from the live USB and choose the Try option. When the desktop starts, open the app "Gparted" see if you can select the "fresh Samsung SSD" from the top right drop down menu. Edit your question and tell us if the laptop has another SSD with Windows installed and if bitlocker is active in Windows.
